# How is the tag search implemented?

Tags: support, tags

How are tags stored in the database and how are they used to search the question if there are multiple tags associated with that question?

Answer (score 11):

Tags are stored both de-normalized and normalized. At least that is what I learned from the SEDE datamodel and some feedback from SE developers.

The `posts` table (with `id` as its primarykey) has a `tags` column that for example holds `<jquery><javascript><css>`.

The `tags` table holds all tags in a `id` (primary key) and `tagname` where `tagname` holds a single tag like `haskell` or `c++`.

The relation between a post and its tags is stored in the relation table called `posttags` with two foreignkey columns, `postid` and `tagid`. The former is for the relation to the `posts` table, the latter to the `tags` table.

Searching in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can be done rather [naively and with the cost of a full table scan](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/467825):

```
select top 100 id as [Post Link] 
from posts
where tags like '%<haskell>%'
order by creationdate desc
```

or with proper [inner joins](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/467827)

```
select top 100 p.id as [Post Link] 
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where tagname ='haskell'
order by p.creationdate desc
```

See the [documentation of the data model on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) or the [ERD](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250439/158100) for more details.

Comment: This is of course assuming that the live schema pretty closely resembles the SEDE schema. Not saying it doesn't of course, but I don't recall seeing anything confirming or denying it.

Comment: `where tagname typically contains haskell.` - are you suggesting that the `haskell` tag is duplicated in the tags table or that it is the most popular tag? :D

Comment: @KeithHall isn't Haskell the next jQuery?

Answer (score -12):

You can use this syntax in the search field appearing at the top right side:

```
[c++]
```

or

```
[javascript][css]
```

Comment: The question reads as asking about how tag searching works on the back end, not _how to_ search by tags. _"How are tags are stored in the database"_ is the first line part of the question, after all.